# Angular 10 upgrade messed up ag-grid-angular dropdown look-n-feel

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular10

My ag-grid-angular version has been upgraded to 24.0.0. as a process of Angular 10 upgrade (npm update --all).
Everything works fine in terms of functionality, angular material components look-n-feel, and third party libraries I am using (e.g. ag-angular-grid, Highchart, splitter, ag-grid, etc..)

But somehow I have lost the default look-n-feel of the ag-angular-grid dropdown (editing grid - cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor')

Here's the comparison of look-n-feel before and after upgrade for more clarity.
[image: ag-angular-grid dropdown comparison before & after upgrade]

Version after angular 10 upgrade (package.json):

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1001.1",
"@angular/animations": "^10.1.2",
"@angular/cdk": "^10.2.1",
"@angular/common": "^10.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "^10.1.2",
"@angular/core": "^10.1.2",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
"@angular/forms": "^10.1.2",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
"@angular/material": "^10.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^10.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.1.2",
"@angular/router": "^10.1.2",
"@types/jest": "^26.0.14",
"ag-grid-angular": "^24.0.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^24.0.0",
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Something you should check... There was a major redesign of ag-grid themes from version 22 to 23. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-v23-migration/

Comment: Thanks Chris! Documentation helped resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing ag-grid and ag-theme-material css files into styles.scss resolved the issue. Thanks to Chris for the direction and documentation.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-v23-migration/

Import these files into "styles.scss" file as shown below, that's it!

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css";
```

or

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-grid";
@import "~ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-theme-material/sass/legacy/ag-theme-material-v22-compat";
```